# Saving List<KeyValuePair<int,string> to a DB with EF 4.3

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an information that is related to my logical entity class, that is stored as a `List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>`.

How do I reflect this in my EF code first entities classes to correctly save this data into a database?

Comment: Can you express the `KeyValuePair` as a class?

Comment: Yes, it can be a separate class, but then I'd face the question of how to link back to a "parent holder" from that new class. I need a code example as it seems =)

Answer (score 1):

When your list entities can e another object then it can be resolved as one to many relationship. So in database it will be two tables with one two many relationship.

So you can add the child entities to the parent

```
        Car car = new Car();
        car.Parts.Add(new Part());
```

Where car has an Parts navigation property defines one to many parts relationship

Good Luck!

Comment: I doubt this example has to do anything with Entity Framework. It requires special way of properties declaration in a class.